# Spring Dependency Mess - conflict with Spring Boot 2.5.4 and Spring Cloud 3.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I am trying to update an application which already pulls in the kitchen sink (or perhaps a few, they're joined at the hip) and I am sorting through version conflicts.

I want to update to Spring Boot 2.5+ and also use Spring Cloud Consul - I am attempting to pull in:

1. spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:3.0.3
2. spring-boot:2.5.4

For bonus points, within spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery, I am seeing that it pulls in reactor-core:3.4.6 and at the same time reactor-extra:3.4.3 (which pulls in reactor-core:3.4.5).  The list goes on and on ...

1. https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery/3.0.3/jar - original point of contention is that it pulls in spring boot 2.4.6 ... it was advertised as supporting 2.5+, then shouldn't the version reference 2.5+?
2. https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/3.0.3/jar - this to me is just plain laziness, right below reactor-core is reactor-extra, why wouldn't the Spring developers make extra pull in the same version of core?  See: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-extra/3.4.3/jar

While this is a trivial problem to solve, it shouldn't be my problem.  Am I missing something, or is this just the way it is and I shouldn't expect more?

Comment: you should manage this via boms, not explicitly. [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) is a matrix of what cloud and boot versions work in tandem.

Comment: spring cloud 2020.0.x is compatible with both boot 2.4.x and 2.5.x and should be managed by the bom. Can you show your build dependency file?

Comment: I can, but my question is more of a philosophical one.  A BOM is going to be similar to using exclusions.

Comment: not even close. you will take two boms, and _never_ manage any version explicitly. at least, imho. we do that. we have one common bom for everyone, where inside we import cloud and boot boms.

Comment: So, in the BOM, would I need to declare a version for reactor-extra / reactor-core?  How else would I get them to coalesce?

Comment: 1) you need to tag me with `@` - otherwise, I have no idea you posted a message. 2) you use a feature where you _import_ other boms in your bom. For [example see here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html), where you can do : `dependencies {
    api platform('com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.8')
}`. Notice how this imports a bom, same thing you need to do for cloud/boot _dependencies bom_.

Comment: no exclusions needed and no version specified. Those versions should come from spring boot which has precedence.

Comment: @spencergibb the problem is that I see no version of `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:3.0.3` that would be taken into spring-cloud-dependencies. At least, I can't see it in maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to look at [this compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) between cloud and boot dependencies. Then, you need (for example) to generate *your* bom, where you import

- [the correct cloud dependencies bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies)
- [spring boot dependencies bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies)

These boms, internally, either import *other* boms, like for example [consul, the one you are interested in](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Hoxton.SR12/spring-cloud-dependencies-Hoxton.SR12.pom), which is at version `2.2.8.RELEASE`. Look in the `properties` tag in that file and see this:

```
<spring-cloud-consul.version>2.2.8.RELEASE</spring-cloud-consul.version>
```

specifically:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-consul.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can then look [at the specific consul bom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-consul-dependencies/2.2.8.RELEASE/spring-cloud-consul-dependencies-2.2.8.RELEASE.pom) and see that the version `consul-discovery` is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Same pattern to find out what version is where can be done for reactor dependencies.

---

From my 10 minutes investing into this, I don't see a version of `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:3.0.3` that would be included in a `cloud-dependecies`.

You could *still* try to force a certain version of a dependency. We just recently [had such a problem in spring-cloud-kubernetes, internally](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/849).

This may or may not work, though.

Comment: The solution for me in this case is indeed to use a BOM; however, I would like Spring to manage those dependencies better on its end as it should and can be consistent.

Comment: @Walter this might not be as trivial to find out, especially since "things just work" for a long time. you can look at [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/849) where we hit the same problem. The only reason we fixed it is because someone reported + I had to dig into the maven doc and documentation for an entire day to figure it out. Someone might have done that by accident, in a PR, and we would never know about it - since things "just work". It's complicated. You can report this problem to consul project or better, fix it... I have no better answer :)