# Liveness and readiness probe return 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

My Spring-Boot Application is running on Kubernetes.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.12</version>
</parent>
```

According to Spring-Boot reference, `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` would be enabled automatically.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.14/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes

> These health groups are only enabled automatically if the application is running in a Kubernetes environment.

> They will also be exposed as separate HTTP Probes using Health Groups: `/actuator/health/liveness` and `/actuator/health/readiness`.

But the endpoints (`/actuator/health/liveness` and `/actuator/health/readiness`) in My Spring-Boot Application returns 404, what's wrong here?

The component of `livenessState` and `readinessState` is enabled, but the health group is not.
[image]

I debug the code and find that the method `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.HealthEndpointGroupsBeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization` doesn't work. Because there's no bean instanceof HealthEndpointGroups, Why?

```
/**
 * {@link BeanPostProcessor} to invoke {@link HealthEndpointGroupsPostProcessor}
 * beans.
 */
static class HealthEndpointGroupsBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final ObjectProvider<HealthEndpointGroupsPostProcessor> postProcessors;

    HealthEndpointGroupsBeanPostProcessor(ObjectProvider<HealthEndpointGroupsPostProcessor> postProcessors) {
        this.postProcessors = postProcessors;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        // there's no bean instanceof HealthEndpointGroups here, Why?

        if (bean instanceof HealthEndpointGroups) {
            return applyPostProcessors((HealthEndpointGroups) bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private Object applyPostProcessors(HealthEndpointGroups bean) {
        for (HealthEndpointGroupsPostProcessor postProcessor : this.postProcessors.orderedStream()
                .toArray(HealthEndpointGroupsPostProcessor[]::new)) {
            bean = postProcessor.postProcessHealthEndpointGroups(bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

I try to run the application locally with adding `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variables, to enable probes. But it didn't work as well.

```
/**
 * {@link SpringBootCondition} to enable or disable probes.
 * <p>
 * Probes are enabled if the dedicated configuration property is enabled or if the
 * Kubernetes cloud environment is detected/enforced.
 */
static class ProbesCondition extends SpringBootCondition {

    private static final String ENABLED_PROPERTY = "management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled";

    private static final String DEPRECATED_ENABLED_PROPERTY = "management.health.probes.enabled";

    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
        ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage.forCondition("Probes availability");
        ConditionOutcome outcome = onProperty(environment, message, ENABLED_PROPERTY);
        if (outcome != null) {
            return outcome;
        }
        outcome = onProperty(environment, message, DEPRECATED_ENABLED_PROPERTY);
        if (outcome != null) {
            return outcome;
        }
        if (CloudPlatform.getActive(environment) == CloudPlatform.KUBERNETES) {
            return ConditionOutcome.match(message.because("running on Kubernetes"));
        }
        return ConditionOutcome.noMatch(message.because("not running on a supported cloud platform"));
    }

    private ConditionOutcome onProperty(Environment environment, ConditionMessage.Builder message,
            String propertyName) {
        String enabled = environment.getProperty(propertyName);
        if (enabled != null) {
            boolean match = !"false".equalsIgnoreCase(enabled);
            return new ConditionOutcome(match, message.because("'" + propertyName + "' set to '" + enabled + "'"));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I run application on Kubernetes, but it doesn't work for me. I find that removing dependency of Spring Cloud Sleuth, it would run normally. Is there any conflict between SpringBoot and Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Removing the follow dependency

```
    <!--traceId -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

yaml:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9235
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: ${MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_EXPOSURE_INCLUDE:*}
```

k8s:

```
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/readiness
      port: {{ .Values.deployment.managementPort }}
    failureThreshold: 3
    initialDelaySeconds: 150
    periodSeconds: 10
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 10
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/health/liveness
      port: {{ .Values.deployment.managementPort }}
    failureThreshold: 3
    initialDelaySeconds: 180
    periodSeconds: 10
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 10
```

Comment: (a) are you asking the [`spring.management.port`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) for those actuator URLs? (b) are you using the same `spring.profiles.active` in the cluster as you are locally? IOW, what debugging have you already tried? Don't put that in the comments, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75443172/edit) and provide more details

Comment: The `spring.management.port` and `spring.profiles.active` is right. I can enable probes using the `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled` configuration property. But why not enabled automatically if the application is running in a Kubernetes environment?

Comment: Well, since you didn't post your Deployment yaml, it is still a reasonable question: are you sending the probes to the correct port?

Comment: @mdaniel Ok, I have posted deployment yaml. Yes, I confirm that sending the probes to the correct port. My application integrates Spring Cloud Sleuth. I find that removing dependency of Spring Cloud Sleuth, it would run normally. Is there any conflict between SpringBoot and Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK Health groups are automatically enabled only if the application met below 2 conditions:**

1)Runs in a Kubernetes deployment environment

Spring Boot auto-detects Kubernetes deployment environments by checking the environment for `"*_SERVICE_HOST"` and `"*_SERVICE_PORT"` variables. You can override this detection with the `spring.main.cloud-platform` configuration property. Spring Boot helps you to manage the state of your application and export it with [HTTP Kubernetes Probes using Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes).

2)The `management.health.probes.enabled` property is set to `true`

If the application meets either of the above conditions, then auto-configuration registers.

Refer to Baeldung, [Liveness and Readiness Probes in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-liveness-readiness-probes#auto-config), Auto-Configurations by Mona Mohamadinia, for more information.

Also refer to github link, [Kubernetes readiness probe endpoint returning 404 #22562](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22562) for more information.

Comment: I run application on Kubernetes. But it doesn't work for me. I find that removing dependency of Spring Cloud Sleuth, it would run normally. Is there any conflict between SpringBoot and Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Comment: Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941419/spring-dependency-mess-conflict-with-spring-boot-2-5-4-and-spring-cloud-3-0-3), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello @Holinc, if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting (✔️) or up voting it for greater visibility for community members.